# Does GitHub update my contributions section when I merged my branch into master branch?

Tags: github

I made 28 commits on my `play_grnd` branch. When I merged my branch into `master` branch (or someone merged my branch into `master`),

Does contributions section on my profile page update itself with changes in varying shades of green?

Comment: Yes. Here are some caveats though https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/#common-reasons-that-contributions-are-not-counted

Comment: Thanks! I had read this page but not that section :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does contributions section on my profile page update itself with changes in varying shades of green?

Yes. However, there are [exceptions to how contributions are tracked](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/#common-reasons-that-contributions-are-not-counted) based on the method used for merging a pull request.

> When a pull request is merged and commits are squashed, only the user that merged the pull request and the user that opened the pull request receive contribution credit. No other contributors to the pull request will receive contribution credit.
>
> When rebasing commits, the original author of the commit and the person who rebased the commits, whether on the command line or on GitHub, receives contribution credit.

Comment: What about the date of the contribution? If the PR merger, merge the commits. Will the commits contribution count added to the exact commit and push date or only the merge date?

Answer (score 1):

Commits will only count as contributions (which show up as the shaded green squares on your profile) if they are made to the default branch (`master`, unless you changed it) or the `gh-pages` branch.  That is the main requirement, but other specifics are factored in.

You can read all the details of when a commit counts as a contribution and when it doesn't here:

https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/#commits

Comment: This isn't what I asked, but thanks. The correct answer is in comments above. Update your answer with that and I'll accept this as correct answer :)

Comment: Thanks, but I'll let @osowskit do that... don't want to take credit for his work.  Glad you got your answer.